# php regular expression match prbl about starting with one string but not the other

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace, preg-match

I have to replace some invalid links in html as following:

```
<td><a title="Michel Blanc" href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?title=Michel_Blanc&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">Michel Blanc</a></td>
<td><a title="Pierre Schöller" href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?title=Pierre_Sch%C3%B6ller&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">Pierre Schöller</a></td>
<td><a title="Focus Features" href="http://www.mysite.com/w/Focus_Features">Focus Features</a><br />
<a title="Olivier Treiner" href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?title=Olivier_Treadfadfadfiner&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">Olivier Treiner</a>
<td>1600</td>
```

I want to remove all `<a>` tags but keep the text between `<a></a>` if the href begins with

```
    http://www.mysite.com/index.php?title=
```

and keep the `<a>` tags if the href begins with

```
    http://www.mysite.com/w/
```

here is my regular expression

```
    (<a title="([\s\S])*?" href="http://www\.mysite\.com/index\.php\?title=([\s\S])*?&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">([\s\S])*?</a>)
```

but it involves the third line that I want to keep.
I tested it in http://regexpal.com/

anybody help me?

Comment: What you want is contradictory...

Comment: can u gives us the sample output for your given input..

Comment: You should test your PHP regular expressions on [regex101](http://regex101.com). Regexpal uses JavaScript's (very limited) regex flavor. The reason why you're matching both the third an fourth line, is that `[\s\S]*?` will still go beyond a tag if it has to. Try `title="[^"]*"` for instance. Nevertheless, you should be using a DOM parser.

Comment: @Jerry sorry for I pasted wrong string. I have edit it.

Comment: @worldask Okay, that's better now! Is [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/sU6uA7) (or something like that) what you were looking for? m.buettner already explained why your regex was behaving that way, but if you test it on a link by link basis, there shouldn't be any problem. with your regex. I just find it a bit strange to use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` because they seem to be doing the same thing to me (except that `.*` by default doesn't match newlines, but you don't have newlines in single links and you'd have got [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/tJ2zL6) instead).

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry and m.buettner for your answer and regex101.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Lester, I'll try htmlparsing. And I think your warning is very advisable.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me :

```
(<a title="[^>]*?" href="http://www\.mysite\.com/index\.php\?title=([\s\S])*?&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">([\s\S])*?</a>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
<td><a title="Michel Blanc" href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?title=Michel_Blanc&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">Michel Blanc</a></td>
<td><a title="Pierre Schöller" href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?title=Pierre_Sch%C3%B6ller&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">Pierre Schöller</a></td>
<td><a title="Focus Features" href="http://www.mysite.com/w/Focus_Features">Focus Features</a><br />
<a title="Olivier Treiner" href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php?title=Olivier_Treadfadfadfiner&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1">Olivier Treiner</a>
<td>1600</td>
<a href="http://remove.me.com">remove.me</a>
LOD;
```

A regex way:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
# definitions
(?(DEFINE)
  # all the content from the "a" tag begining until the content 
  # of the "href" attribute 
  (?<atohref>
      <a\b (?> [^h>]++ | \Bh | h(?!ref) )++ href\s*+=\s*+['"]?+
  )

  # all the content until the closing "a" tag 
  (?<untilclosea>
      (?> [^<]++ | <(?!/a>) )++
  )
)

# pattern
    \g<atohref>
    \Qhttp://www.mysite.com/\E
    (?>
        \Qindex.php?title=\E
        [^>]*+>
        ( \g<untilclosea> ) # third group (because of the two named groups)
        </a>
      |
        w/ \g<untilclosea>
        </a> \K      # reset the match (to preserve it)
    )
  | 
    <a\b \g<untilclosea> </a> # all other "a" tags
~x
LOD;

$replacement = '$3';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
echo htmlspecialchars($subject).'<br><br>';
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```